# How to programmatically select a UITextField for editing

Tags: ios6, uitextfield, xcode4.6, eventtrigger

I have a UITextField that I need to select programmatically so when the user taps on a date in a UIDatePicker, it will be sent to that UITextField.

This is the code I have, which does not select the UITextField; I have tried all possible combinations of **UIControlEvent**, but none of them work.  Any other ideas?

```
    //  set textField parameters
if([whichTextField isEqualToString:@"oStartTime"]) {
    oStartTime.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:252.0/255.0 green:255.0/255.0 blue:197.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    [oStartTime sendActionsForControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

}
else if([whichTextField isEqualToString:@"oFinishTime"]) {
    oFinishTime.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:252.0/255.0 green:255.0/255.0 blue:197.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    [oFinishTime sendActionsForControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the UIResponder instance method [becomeFirstResponder](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIResponder/becomeFirstResponder).

Answer (score 3):

yourTextField.becomeFirstResponder()