# How to Open Addressbook New Contact Screen

Tags: addressbook, abaddressbooksource

In my application I have `UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd` on right side of the navigation controller. On tapping of that plus icon I want to open address book in editable mode. Please refer the following image.

How to open address book UI for new contact in editable mode directly?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `AddressBookUI.framework`, there is a class called `ABNewPersonViewController`. Basically, what you want to do is this:

```
ABNewPersonViewController *abnpvc = [[ABNewPersonViewController alloc] init];
[abnpvc setNewPersonViewDelegate: self];
[self presentViewController: abnpvc animated: YES completion: nil];
```

This brings up the view you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks... Its work like a charm.... Is it possible to directly focus on first name field with keyboard on screen?

Comment: This might work: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17975680/how-to-programmatically-select-a-uitextfield-for-editing